# FeedEntryMessageSource method doReceive() is getting blocked

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Threads are getting blocked even after setting connectionTimeOut and readTimeout.

Environment OpenJDK 17, spring integration version 5.5.7

```
private FeedEntryMessageSource feedEntrySource(URL feedURL, String metadataKey) {
    UrlResource urlResource =
        new UrlResource(feedURL) {

          @Override
          protected void customizeConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
            super.customizeConnection(connection);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
          }
        };
    return new FeedEntryMessageSource(urlResource, metadataKey);
  }
```

Here is a sample threaddump snapshot

```
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:172)
- waiting to lock <0x000000043297b4e8> (a java.lang.Object)
```

The blocking might be related to this SO issue. [setting connectionTimeOut and readTimeout not working on UrlResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165245/setting-connectiontimeout-and-readtimeout-not-working-on-urlresource)

Comment: You probably try poll this source too often, e.g. via `fixedRate` instead of `fixedDelay`. So, you call that `doReceive()` concurrently too much while the current one has not returned yet therefore the others are just blocked. Any chances to share with us a simple project to reproduce?

Comment: There is another issue with URLResource. The connection is not getting terminated after specified amount of time. Here is the link to so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165245/setting-connectiontimeout-and-readtimeout-not-working-on-urlresource

Comment: Are you sure that question is not related to this one and non-termination is really a cause of such a dead-lock? I mean probably that info has to included to this question for the whole picture…

Comment: There are two doubts. First is UrlResource not getting timedout and i am sure of this as i have reproduced it in SO question. second one is synchronized block inside doReceive method of FeedEntryMessageSource.

Comment: The timeout solution that is mentioned in docs is not working. here is the link https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/feed.html#other-options

Comment: That’s interesting… what Java do you use ? Any chances to share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with?

Comment: The synchronized block is really an expected behavior: we do connection and entries fetch in one thread. The rest are waiting on this block.When first one is done fetching it stores entries into an in-memory cache and returns a single entry. Now others can get an access, but they don't fetch because there is a cache. So, such a synchronized block is a reasonable optimization. The problem with non-terminating timeout really may lead to such a block... Let me look into your other questions!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `UrlResource` doesn't call `customizeConnection()` from the `getInputStream()` we use in the `FeedEntryMessageSource` logic.

The workaround is like this:

```
        UrlResource urlResource = new UrlResource(url) {

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                URLConnection con = getURL().openConnection();
                customizeConnection(con);
                try {
                    return con.getInputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Close the HTTP connection (if applicable).
                    if (con instanceof HttpURLConnection httpConn) {
                        httpConn.disconnect();
                    }
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
```

See more info in the related question: [setting connectionTimeOut and readTimeout not working on UrlResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73165245/setting-connectiontimeout-and-readtimeout-not-working-on-urlresource)

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. We did the same thing as a workaround and it is working fine. Now, no threads are getting blocked and we are getting read timeouts for urls that were holding the connection before. Also raised GH issue in spring (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28909)