# setting connectionTimeOut and readTimeout not working on UrlResource

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to terminate a connection if no data is being received or server is just keeping the connection open for a url by setting connectionTimeout and readTimeout.

I have create anonymous class of URLResource and fetch the data from url. code block below is of spring project. spring boot version is 2.7.1

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=20000");
  UrlResource urlResource = new UrlResource(url) {

@Override
    protected void customizeConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
      super.customizeConnection(connection);
      connection.setConnectTimeout(4000);
      connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
    }
  };

  InputStream inputStream = urlResource.getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
  br.lines().forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("IO exception");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using a service (http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=20000) that allows to hold connection for specified amount of time to check out the connection termination but the connection is not getting terminate after specified amount of time

Is there any other way to customize urlResource so that timeout can be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `UrlResource.getInputStream()` is missing to call `customizeConnection(con);` in its logic:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    URLConnection con = this.url.openConnection();
    ResourceUtils.useCachesIfNecessary(con);
    try {
        return con.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // Close the HTTP connection (if applicable).
        if (con instanceof HttpURLConnection httpConn) {
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Please, raise a GH issue for [Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues) to address this problem.

As a workaround I see this:

```
        UrlResource urlResource = new UrlResource(url) {

            @Override 
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                URLConnection con = getURL().openConnection();
                customizeConnection(con);
                try {
                    return con.getInputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Close the HTTP connection (if applicable).
                    if (con instanceof HttpURLConnection httpConn) {
                        httpConn.disconnect();
                    }
                    throw ex;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void customizeConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
                super.customizeConnection(connection);
                connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
            }
        };
```

So, I override that `getInputStream()` with the same logic, but also apply our `customizeConnection()` on it. With that fix your test fails like this:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:791)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:726)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1688)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
```

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28909